# Offset date for a Pandas DataFrame date index

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe created as follows:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6),index=dates,columns=list('A'))

                  A
2013-01-01   0.847528
2013-01-02   0.204139
2013-01-03   0.888526
2013-01-04   0.769775
2013-01-05   0.175165
2013-01-06  -1.564826
```

I want to add 15 days to the index.
This does not work>

```
#from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df.index+relativedelta(days=15)
#df.index + DateOffset(days=5)

TypeError: relativedelta(days=+15)
```

I seem to be incapable of doing anything right with indexes....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can use [DateOffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6),index=dates,columns=list('A'))
>>> df.index = df.index + pd.DateOffset(days=15)
>>> df
                   A
2013-01-16  0.015282
2013-01-17  1.214255
2013-01-18  1.023534
2013-01-19  1.355001
2013-01-20  1.289749
2013-01-21  1.484291
```

Comment: Great thanks!It seems I did not realize the need to precede the DateOffset with pd.

Comment: I was looking a solution for the same issue and this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @dartdog Whether you have to use the prefix `pd.` depends on how you imported the functionality. If you did `from pandas import DateOffset`, then you can (and have to) just write `DateOffset`. If you did `import pandas`, then it's `pandas.DateOffset`.

Answer (score 10):

Marginally shorter/more direct is `tshift`:

```
df = df.tshift(15, freq='D')
```

[Link to a list of freq aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

Comment: The above link seems to be broken, perhaps link to this ? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#shifting-lagging

Comment: Thanks @fixxxer, that's a slightly different link but I've updated the link.

Comment: Updated link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases

Answer (score 0):

If need convert it to `DatetimeIndex` and add days use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) + pd.Timedelta('15 days')
```

If already `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.index += pd.Timedelta('15 days')
```