# How to add/subtract time (hours, minutes, etc.) from a Pandas DataFrame.Index whos objects are of type datetime.time?

Tags: python, datetime, time, pandas

I've got a DataFrame whose index is just datetime.time and there's no method in  DataFrame.Index and datetime.time to shift the time. datetime.time has replace but that'll only work on individual items of the Series?

Here's an example of the index used:

```
In[526]:  dfa.index[:5]
Out[526]: Index([21:12:19, 21:12:20, 21:12:21, 21:12:21, 21:12:22], dtype='object')

In[527]:  type(dfa.index[0])
Out[527]: datetime.time
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820280/add-a-date-offset-to-a-pandas-date-index

Comment: What is the output of type(df.index)?

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud pandas.core.index.Index but if I type(df.index[0]) that is datetime.time.

Comment: @DreamAwake Make use of `pandas.Timestamp()` to convert your current index to a timestamp index and then do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Liam's link looks great, but also check out `pandas.Timedelta` - looks like it plays nicely with NumPy's and Python's time deltas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html

```
pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=10) + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Using df.index + pd.Timedelta(hours=12) gives me the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timedelta'". The index itself is pandas.core.index.Index but each value is a datetime.time which somehow interferes with the tshift() method as well as Timedelta additions.

Comment: See Mostafa's comment on your original question re. conversion to `Timestamps`.

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud are you guys really able to take a series or index of datetime.time values and convert directly with pandas.Timestamp() or even with the method .to_timestamp() ? These only throw errors for me. I'm considering joining the datetime.time to a date and forming a DatetimeIndex outright but that's not optimal since my dataset only logs time.

Comment: Please post an example of the index you are using.

Comment: Posted. Let me know if you need more detail. Thanks for the help!

Comment: df_series.index = (df_series.index + pd.Timedelta(days=1))

Comment: what is the periods for?

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me:

```
>> print(df)
                          TotalVolume  Symbol
2016-04-15 09:00:00       108400       2802.T
2016-04-15 09:05:00       50300        2802.T

>> print(df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.values) - datetime(2016, 4, 15)))

             TotalVolume  Symbol
09:00:00     108400       2802.T
09:05:00     50300        2802.T
```

Answer (score 0):

The Philippe solution but cleaner:

My subtraction data is: '2018-09-22T11:05:00.000Z'

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df_modified = pd.to_datetime(df_reference.index.values) - datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 22, 11, 5, 0)
```