# matplotlib double bar graph with pandas series

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, tuples, bar-chart

I have the following:

```
indyes = tuple(yesSeries.index)
indno = tuple(nodSeries.index)
width = 3

p1 = plt.bar(indyes, yesSeries, label="Example one", color='SkyBlue')
p2 = plt.bar(indno, nodSeries, label="Example two", color='IndianRed')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('bar number')
plt.ylabel('bar height')

plt.title('Epic Graph\nAnother Line! Whoa')

plt.show()
```

It plots my graph as a stacked bar graph:
[image]

When I try to add `+ width` to the second bar graph, `indno + width` so they are not stacked, rather side by side I get the following error: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple`.

I have set my Pandas Series into a tuple to extract the date and count information.

**How can I get two parallel vertical bar plots?**

Comment: What's the reason to use a `tuple` here? Do you want to add [3 days to each item in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954093/how-to-add-subtract-time-hours-minutes-etc-from-a-pandas-dataframe-index-wh)?

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have my dataframe grouped by a timestamp, and my final dataset is a pandas.core.series.Series with a timestamp and counts. I'm using the tuple to access the timestamp and counts in the series for my x and y vales in my plot. The plot seems to  be working fine, I prefer 2 bars rather than a stacked bar.

Comment: Not sure if that answers my question. Anyways, you might also decide to provide a [mcve] here, such that people can simply provide an answer without understanding the motivation.

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest No, I do not want to add 3 days. I want to have 2 horizontal bar graphs, and not stacked bar graphs.

Comment: Horizontal bar graphs are created via [barh](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html).

Comment: @a1234 Maybe you meant that you want two parallel vertical bar plots, not stacked. Am I right?

Comment: @ Cedric Zoppolo yes , that's what I mean, sorry! thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for can be done creating a `DataFrame` from your `Series` and then using the `plot.bar` function.

In below code I generate data and create the graph as you may want to.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
times = pd.date_range('2018-09-01', periods=7, freq='5D')
yesSeries = pd.Series([1800,2000,3000,1000,2000,1500,1700], index=times)
nodSeries = pd.Series([200,500,700,600,300,50,0], index=times)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Example one":yesSeries,"Example two":nodSeries})
ax = df.plot.bar(color=["SkyBlue","IndianRed"], rot=0, title="Epic Graph\nAnother Line! Whoa")
ax.set_xlabel("date")
ax.set_ylabel("counts")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(times.strftime("%b %d %Y")))
plt.show()
```

This results in below graph.

[image: Bar plot]

If it seems that the dates appear to be cluttered you can  insert below line before the `plt.show()` code:

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Which would result in below graph.

[image: Bar plot with dates with autofmt]