# Add 24 hours to time in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

A dataframe column with values in 'time' format needs to be added with 24 hours.
eg: if 24 hours is getting added with value 10:30:30 then result expected is 34:30:30,the below code piece(added as image) generates '0 days 10:30:30'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5G31.png)
can anyone please guide me not get 0days and to get the 24 hours to add with hour value.

Comment: Please add your code into your question, not a screenshot of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/subtract time (hours, minutes, etc.) from a Pandas DataFrame.Index whos objects are of type datetime.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954093/how-to-add-subtract-time-hours-minutes-etc-from-a-pandas-dataframe-index-wh)

Answer (score 1):

**Sample**:

```
N = 10
np.random.seed(2019)
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 15:30:20', periods=N, freq='13.3T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'vstime': np.abs(np.random.choice(rng, size=N) - 
                                 np.random.choice(rng, size=N))})

print (df)
    vstime
0 00:39:54
1 00:13:18
2 01:06:30
3 01:19:48
4 00:13:18
5 00:13:18
6 01:46:24
7 01:06:30
8 00:39:54
9 01:46:24
```

Instead your code use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html).

```
df['vstime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['vstime']) + pd.Timedelta(24, unit='h')
```

Formating timedelta is not native suported, so need custom function:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

df['duration'] = df['vstime'].apply(f)
print (df)
           vstime  duration
0 1 days 00:39:54  24:39:54
1 1 days 00:13:18  24:13:18
2 1 days 01:06:30  25:06:30
3 1 days 01:19:48  25:19:48
4 1 days 00:13:18  24:13:18
5 1 days 00:13:18  24:13:18
6 1 days 01:46:24  25:46:24
7 1 days 01:06:30  25:06:30
8 1 days 00:39:54  24:39:54
9 1 days 01:46:24  25:46:24
```