# Python - Using Pandas to calculate time between dates for each unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have been stuck with this for a while and i would appreciate some help. Here is a simplified version of a pandas dataframe i am working with:

```
ID  Date
1   16/07/2020 14:11:12
1   17/07/2020 15:12:11
1   16/07/2020 15:32:44
1   16/07/2020 17:11:24
2   19/07/2020 06:11:12
2   19/07/2020 12:12:11
2   20/07/2020 14:32:44
2   20/07/2020 02:11:24
```

I would like to calculate the time by using the minimum value for each ID and subtracting it for rows that hold the same ID. However, i want the format to be in hh:mm:ss where if the difference is more than 24 hours it would be 37:44:22 for example.

Here is how i would the results should look like.

```
ID  Date                    time
1   16/07/2020 14:11:12     00:00:00
1   17/07/2020 18:32:23     28:21:11
1   16/07/2020 18:32:44     04:21:32
1   16/07/2020 17:11:24     00:00:12
2   19/07/2020 06:11:12     00:00:00
2   19/07/2020 12:12:12     06:01:00
2   20/07/2020 14:32:44     26:20:32
```

I have found previous questions such as this [Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu) but most questions subtract dates from the same row. However, in my case i have to find the id with the earliest date, and use it to find the time difference for rows that carry the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then subtract minimal per group by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and last use custom function for custom format of [timedeltas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55065189/2901002):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

df['time1'] = df['Date'].sub(df.groupby('ID')['Date'].transform('min')).apply(f)
print (df)
   ID                Date      time     time1
0   1 2020-07-16 14:11:12  00:00:00  00:00:00
1   1 2020-07-17 18:32:23  28:21:11  28:21:11
2   1 2020-07-16 18:32:44  04:21:32  04:21:32
3   1 2020-07-16 17:11:24  00:00:12  03:00:12
4   2 2020-07-19 06:11:12  00:00:00  00:00:00
5   2 2020-07-19 12:12:12  06:01:00  06:01:00
6   2 2020-07-20 14:32:44  26:20:32  32:21:32
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Thank you for the fast answer :D