# Add time in hours (4,5 h) to a certain time

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, time, addition

I have one dataframe with two columns I would like to add together

I have one column named 'Bedtime Start', which consists of values like 12:15 am and 10:31 pm.

I have another column named 'Midpoint (h)', which consists of values like 4,534 and 3,22.

I would like to add the Midpoint hours to the Bedtime Start in a new column called 'Time at Midpoint' consisting of values like 18:45 am etc.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954093/how-to-add-subtract-time-hours-minutes-etc-from-a-pandas-dataframe-index-wh

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.